# Crystal Reports remove multiple instances of HTML tags within a string field

Tags: html, sql, replace, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to remove all the HTML tags from a string field in a Crystal Report, but keep the text. This field is going to be the header in a crosstab and the HTML tags have to be removed. I've created a SQL expression which will has removed a lot of the static tags like

and , but the dynamic tags such as  and  I'm having trouble with. I can remove the first tag in the field using ExtractString (https://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/2943) function, but if there are other instances of that same tag, it won't remove them. How can I get every instance of the dynamic tags while still being able to use is as a column header?

local stringvar linkreplace := ("<a" in {FieldName} then ('<a ' + ExtractString({FieldName}, '<a ', '>') + '>') else "");
local stringvar spanreplace := (if '<span' in {FormDetails.FieldName} then ('<span' + ExtractString({FieldName}, '<span', '>') + '>') else "");
local stringvar imgreplace := (if "<img" in {FormDetails.FieldName} then ('<img ' + ExtractString({FieldName}, '<img ', '/>') + '/>') else "");
local stringvar headerreplace := (if "<hr" in {FormDetails.FieldName} then ('<hr ' + ExtractString({FieldName}, '<hr ', '>') + '>') else "");

replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
{FieldName}
,linkreplace,'')
,spanreplace,'')
,imgreplace,'')
,headerreplace,'')

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the string? I'd like to test a solution with your data.

Comment: <span style="color:#111111">Text:<span style="color:#201F1E"><span style="color:#201F1E"> More Text <a target="_blank" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">http://www.stackoverflow.com/ this is more text <a  href="https://www.google.com/">google.com.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work with the solution I had in mind. Probably because the open tags are not properly balance by close tags.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, works perfectly fine; I just needed to enclose your sample in HTML tags. The solution uses a 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library).
Ken Hamady maintains a list of such UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

This particular UFL provides a function for converting HTML text to plain text.
Sorry, but I believe forum etiquette precludes me from naming the UFL.

[image: Crystal Reports sample converting HTML to plain text]